# WooCommerce Product Short Description

Tags: woocommerce, meta-tags

Wondering if anyone knew if it is possible to change the WooCommerce 'Product Short Description' panel heading on the backend product edit page - Would love to be able to change it to be 'Product Details & Features' to make it clearer for my client.

Screengrab of the panel I mean: http://madebystudio313.com.au/WooComerce-SPD.png

Ta heaps in advance